# student to be able to pay for course before registration

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

So i have made a courses detail page that will be shown to students who want to take particular course. On clicking that course they'll be redirected to enroll page where they'll have to provide their personal information and then on clicking 'Continue with registration' button a stripe form opens up where they'll be paying for that course and get themselves registered in a firestore collection called 'students'.

Now before paying there is no userId and no kind of login session in place. So i am trying to implement the stripe payments functionality and so far i was able to send stripe checkout form data in realtime database but the payment is not succeeding. I tried using different functions but still firestore cloud function is not accepting the credentials that i am sending. I am unable to understand why is the test payment not succeeding yet. Here is the function

```
exports.stripeCharge = functions.firestore
    .document('payments/{userId}/info/{paymentId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
        // ... Your code here
        const payment = change.after.data();
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const paymentId = context.params.paymentId;

        console.log('payment => ' + payment);
        console.log('userId => ' + userId);
        console.log('paymentId => ' + paymentId);

        // checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
        if (!payment || payment.charge) return;

        return db.doc('users/'+userId).get().then(documentSnapshot => {

            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                console.log('Document retrieved successfully.');
            }

            return documentSnapshot.data();

        }).then(customer => {

            const amount = payment.amount;
            const idempotency_key = paymentId; // prevent duplicate charges
            const source = payment.token.id;
            const currency = 'usd';
            const charge = {amount, currency, source};

            console.log('inside stripe.charges => ' + charge);

            return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key });

        })
        .then(charge =>{
            console.log('set(charge) ' + charge);
            let timestamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
            db.doc('payments/'+userId+'/info/'+paymentId)
            .set(
            {charge: charge,timestamp}, {merge: true});
            return true;
        })
});
```

Realtime database is showing me [image: this] everytime i test the stripe payment.

Angular Component Code

```
  constructor(private pmt: PaymentService, private functions: AngularFireFunctions) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pmt.showId();
    this.handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: environment.stripeKey,
      image: 'https://oc1.ocstatic.com/images/logo_small.png',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: token => {
        this.pmt.processPayment(token, this.amount)
      },

    });
  }

  handlePayment(e) {
    const user = this.pmt.showId();
    this.handler.open({
      name: 'FireStarter',
      description: 'Pay your Dues',
      amount : this.amount,
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Payment service

```
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, 
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
        if(auth) this.userId = auth.uid;
        console.log(this.userId);
      })
  }

  async showId() {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise()
  }

  processPayment(token: any, amount) {
    const payment = {token, amount}
    return this.db.list(`/payment/${this.userId}`).push(payment)
  }
```

I am not even sure why i am trying to fetch uid through Angular Auth even though there is no user session active at the moment. I just tried following [this](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-stripe-payments-part-2-firebase-cloud-functions-backend/) tutorial

NEW CODE FOCUSED ON REALTIME DATABASE

```
exports.stripeCharge = functions.firestore
  .document('/users/{userId}/payments/{paymentId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const payment = event.data.data()
    const userId = event.params.userId
    const paymentId = event.params.paymentId

    // checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
    if (!payment || payment.charge) return

    return admin.firestore()
      .doc(`/users/${userId}`)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot
      })
      .then(customer => {
        const amount = payment.price * 100 // amount must be in cents
        const idempotency_key = paymentId  // prevent duplicate charges
        const source = payment.token.id
        const currency = 'usd'
        const description = 'irl Map Fine Print'
        const charge = {amount, currency, source}

        return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key })
     })
     .then(charge => {
       admin.firestore()
        .doc(`/users/${userId}/payments/${paymentId}`)
        .set({
          charge: charge
        }, { merge: true })
     })
   })
```

The response in realtime is still the same as before.

Comment: Do you see any error in the Cloud Function log?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec nope the log shows me nothing. If the function was triggered perfectly then the status of payment would have been succeeded but right now i am not even seeing the status property in database

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the two database services offered by Firebase: the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore).

As a matter of fact, you are writing to the Realtime Database but your Cloud Function is triggered when a document is [written](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) in Cloud Firestore.

You need to adapt your Cloud Function as follows:

```
functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{paymentId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

        const payment = change.after.val();   // <- See the change here
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const paymentId = context.params.paymentId;

        //....

    });
```

---

Then you have to modify this line

```
return db.doc('users/' + userId).get().then(documentSnapshot => {})
```

because, again, you are using the [Cloud Firestore syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) and not the Realtime Database one (you shoudl use the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) method)

---

In addition, note that you need to adapt the way you chain your promises:

In particular `documentSnapshot.data()` does not return a Promise

```
return db.doc('users/' + userId).get().then(documentSnapshot => {

    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        console.log('Document retrieved successfully.');
    }

    return documentSnapshot.data();  <- Here documentSnapshot.data() does not return a promise

}).then(customer => {})
```

---

I would kindly suggest that you re-write your code in the light of these remarks and if you encounter new errors, that you add to your initial question the new code together with the errors you are encountering.

Comment: it worked the same way like before. The new transaction is created in realtime database but there is nothing like `status: succeeded` property in it.

Comment: Once the transaction gets succeeded it will return back a 200 response to me then i'll save that student into firestore collection named 'students'

Comment: I would very much like to talk with you in a room

Comment: I just made an edit and added the new code focused on realtime database. It still shows me the same response

Comment: Are you using the **two** database services at the same time? The Realtime Database AND Cloud Firestore.

Comment: yes unfortunately. I only wanted to use firestore cloud and not realtime databases and realtime is only being used for stripe integration. I wanted to know if there was anyway to create a collection in cloud firestore to handle all the stripe functionality then it would have been great but couldn't find any help for that too

Comment: You could very well use only Firestore. You just need to look at the way you write and read in Firestore and adapt the code from the tutorial you refer to.

Comment: In that case my previous function could be in right format. Don't you think so?

Comment: Possibly. It all depends on which collection you write in Firestore. But there is one point that is not clear: why do you do `db.doc('users/'+userId).get()` (Or `admin.firestore()
      .doc(`/users/${userId}`)
      .get()`)? You never use the customer object you get back.

Comment: Exactly my confusion it is. I just followed the tutorial in the video so i wasn't sure which uid i needed to pass to. So that's why i was looking for a way to integrate thises functions [link]https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js . I think these are the ones that i need to use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202320/discussion-between-ahsan-nissar-and-renaud-tarnec).

Comment: Is this the right way to trigger function stripe_customers

`processPayment(amount) {
return this.db.collection('stripe_customers').doc(this.userId).set(amount, { merge: true });
}`
I need to pass userId which i guess i can auto generate too. But i am not sure about the syntax.
db is actually an object from `import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore'`;